# reading from input stream of socket without busy waiting in JAVA

Tags: java, sockets

i want to read from input stream when i connect to a server socket.
but there may exist some delays between messages how can i read from input stream without busy loop ?

```
string mes = socketReader.readLine();
```

above line returns null when no input provided in socket input stream.
i want to be notified somehow when a message is ready in input stream.

tnx

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked [asynchronous IO](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html)?

Comment: NIO is the prettiest way to go about it, but the API is somewhat intricate. Consider one of the NIO wrappers such as Grizzly, NeTTY, NIOFramework or Apache MINA.

Answer (score 1):

In a GUI context, [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) may help: let `doInBackground()` do the reading, use `process()` for interim reuslts, and `done()` to wrap up. You can register a `PropertyChangeListener` to drive a progress indicator. This [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SwingWorker) expands on the idea, and a [back port](https://swingworker.dev.java.net/) to Java 1.5 is available. Here's a [simple example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata) that reads from a JDBC source instead of a stream, but the idea is the same.