# Displaying serial port output data in text-box in efficient way in java

Tags: java, textbox, label

I am making a GUI application for operating a remote device through serial port. For this I am using two threads - "reading from" and "writing to" serial port. My main application frame contains one menubar with menuItems and submenu items and one scrollable text area. Now I am putting all the output from serial port to text area so its just feeling like the console. The serial port shell give me command output something like this

```
line1 word1 word2 wordd3 word4 word5 :
    line2 word1 = 0x00000000
    line3 word2 = 0x00000000
line3Word1 : line3word2
line4Word1 : line4Word2
line5Word1 : line5word2
line6Word1 : line6Word2
```

Now I want to put some lines in my main frame in labels. Something like this.

```
line4Word1(in label1) : line4Word2(in label2)
line5Word1(in label3) : line5word2(in label4)
```

Now If i will put the checks on strings line4Word1 and line5Word1 at reading serial ports, I fear will be able to process the string and create labels while realtime data recieving?

Can anybody suggest me some better way to do this?

I am sorry if I am unable to explain the problem clearly. But If not clear please let me know I will explain it better way....

Answer (score 3):

For your scrolling area, the append() method of [JTextArea](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String)) happens to be thread-safe. To get thread-safe updates to other GUI components, I'd go with [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941873/reading-from-input-stream-of-socket-without-busy-waiting-in-java/1941926#1941926).