# Server reading from the socket's input stream only if it has data

Tags: java, sockets, io

I'm trying to implement a ridiculously simplistic chat client and a chat server. My goal is to learn to get comfortable with `Socket`s rather than come up with a reasonable chat implementation. However, I want to ensure that common sense is respected too. This question is about server code

Suppose, a connection was established (`accept()` returned) and now the server needs to service that particular client (using a separate thread as it should)

```java
public class SimpleChatServer {
    // possibly something else
    private static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private static final List<OutputStream> outputStreamList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private static void start() {
        try (var serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000)) {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                executorService.submit(() -> serviceClient(socket));
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, I need a reasonable `serviceClient()` implementation. The first step is to register that socket's output stream because the server needs to read incoming strings and "broadcast" them to every connected client

```java
    private static void serviceClient(Socket socket) {
        registerOutputStream(socket);
        // some other code I haven't written yet
    }
```

```java
    private static void registerOutputStream(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        // so that I "foreach" it once I receive a message to broadcast
        outputStreamList.add(socket.getOutputStream());
    }
```

Now I'm at a loss. How does that server know whether a client wrote something so that it can read from the socket's input stream? I need the code that basically says, "If the input stream has something, read and broadcast it to clients; if not, just keep on waiting till it does". Sounds a lot like an infinite loop with constant condition checks (inefficient). Or a client needs to be able to communicate to the server, "I wrote, you can read". It could be implemented using concurrency synchronization mechanisms, but it's a weird design feature to have a client and a server to have shared synchronization objects (even for such a simplistic app). What is the reasonable solution to this?

I don't think ["have you looked asynchronous IO"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1941929/22186847) may count for an adequate answer. If it's indeed what I should consider, can you provide some details (possibly simple code snippets)? I'm not very familiar with that package

Comment: Have you considered having two threads for each client, one for reading from the socket and one for writing to it? The reader thread is normally blocking on a read.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I have, but I still need to figure out how to avoid both checking the condition all the time and introducing synchronizers shared by clients and the server. When is it time to read?

Comment: Sockets operate in blocking mode by default.  So you could simply read from it unconditionally and let it block the calling thread until data arrives. If you don't want to block the calling thread, then you will have to use non-blocking/asynchronous I/O, such as via a `Selector`, to notify you when data is available to read.

Comment: "How does that server know whether a client wrote something so that it can read from the socket's input stream?": *by reading from the input stream.* No doubt someone will suggest `InputStream.available()`, but that doesn't guarantee that a complete message is available, unless you magically know the length in advance, so it isn't a viable solution.